# How to repeat an iteration with the same amount of jump

Tags: python-3.x

Wish you are all well.
I am super new in Python and at the moment am having a difficulty to construct a solution for the problem I am having, I doubt I could present the problems correctly but here goes:

0. I have to make a variable with the name current position and init value of 0 and should be incremented by the number of jump.
1. I have to make two variables that receive integer input. Jump and Target.
2. I have to define the number range, between 0 to 9, so range(0, 10).
3. The jump defines how many number does the code have to skip when it starts to iterate.
4. The target is the number of which when the jump lands on it, it will exit the loop.
5. For example, if the target is number 1 and the jump is 2, it means, in the first jump, it will skip the target. And it will continue to do so until it lands on 1.

The problem is, I could not figure out what the problem is.
Here is my humble code...

```
jump = int(input())
target = int(input())
current_position = 0

    for i in range(0, 10):
        current_position += jump
        if jump == target:
            print(current_position, end=" ")
```

I really need some advise here, please.
Thank you.

Comment: Your point# 4 and 5 are not very clear. As per point# 3 in your for loop it would start with something like if (i < jump): continue  - this is to continue or skip the initial iteration by amount specified in jump. There is no change happening in value of jump or target so if target is less then jump then condition jump == target will never be reached.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, thanks for your reply man. Based on your reply, it is true that the target will never be reached because it is less than the jump. Hoewever, the jump will continue again and again until it is equal to 1. I have an example of it, not the best but I try:

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

if the jump is two, it will make a pattern
2
4
6
8
0
since it will not hit the target, after it has reached zero, it should exit the loop and print('target is not found')

I am sorry that it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The series/range you have is increasing and there no indication or point in your requirements about a decrement, so not sure how last number will go to 0.

Please refer to code below, see if this is something you are looking for -

```
jump = int(input("Enter value for jump -> "))
target = int(input("Enter value for target -> "))
current_position = 0
for current_position in range(jump,10, jump):
    print (current_position)
    if current_position == target:
        print ('Target found and current position = ', current_position)
        break
    elif (current_position == len(range(0,10))-jump):
        print ('Target not found.')
        break
    else:
        continue
```